# Equation of parabola that passes through two points and vertex has coordinates ($x_v$, $0$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, quadratics

I can't solve the last exercises in a worksheet of Pre-Calculus problems. It says:

Quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ determines a parabola that passes through points $(0, 2)$ and $(4, 2)$, and its vertex has coordinates $(x_v, 0)$.

a) Calculate coordinate $x_v$ of parabola's vertex.

b) Calculate $a, b$ and $c$ coefficients.

How can I get parabola's equation with this information and find what is requested?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Plug the two points into the equation of the parabola. You get two equations in three unknowns (a, b and c). Then, you know that when the parabola is zero, it's derivative is also zero. Equate the two to get the third equation. Solve three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: One short-cut:  $f(0)=2$ means $c = ?$

Comment: @RohitPandey Not quite. The derivative is $0$ at the vertex, not when the "parabola is $0$".

Comment: @EthanBolker - Doesn't the vertex having a y-coordinate of $0$ imply that the parabola is $0$ there?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks, I tried that and $c$ equals 2 in that case. But still I have two unknown variables $a$ and $b$. How can I calculate them?

Comment: @RohitPandey Yes in this example but your hint read in isolation suggests a general principle that's wrong.

Comment: The equation of the parabola in vertex form is $f(x)=a(x-x_v)^2+k$ and you're also given $f(x_v)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(0)=c$ and we are given $f(0)=2$, we see immediately that $c=2.$

Furthermore, the equation in vertex form is $f(x)=a(x-x_v)^2+k$,

and since we are given $f(x_v)=0$, we see that $k=0,$ i.e., $f(x)=a(x-x_v)^2$.

From $a(x-x_v)^2=ax^2+bx+2$ we see that $ax_v^2 = 2$ and $-2ax_v=b.$

Since $f(4)=f(0)=2$, $(4-x_v)^2=x_v^2$, which means $x_v=2$.  Thus $a=\frac12$ and $b=-2.$

Comment: Thank you. Very much apreciated. One question though: how did you concluded  −2= ?

Comment: $ax^2-2ax_vx+ax_v^2=ax^2+bx+2$ for all $x$ implies $-2ax_v=b$ and $ax_v^2=2$

Comment: I understand more, now. One last question: how did you reached $(4 - x_v)^2 = x_v^2$. 
Where did $a$ went ?

Comment: We have $a(4-x_v^2)^2=ax_v^2;$ divide both sides by $a$ (which is not zero -- otherwise we would have a line, not a parabola)

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

A graph is a collection of points where the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of these points are in a relationship. We sometimes write $y$ instead of $f(x)$ to stress this fact.

Your equation

$$
y=ax^2+bx+c
$$
is this relation.

Try plugging in the coordinates of your given points, which you know lie on this curve (so they will satisfy the linking relation between the coordinate pairs)

I would definitely start with the point $(0,2)$, zeros are always good to have around.

You will get

$$
2=a\cdot0^2+b\cdot0+c
$$

Then I would try with the other two points.

Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks. I am left with this equation $16a + 4b = 0$ if I plug known points. Still have missing pieces.

Comment: @F.Zer I know, you need $3$ points to determine a parabola. But I think you made a mistake. I believe that it should not be $0$ on the right hand side

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_java Previous step was: $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
  a(0)^2+b*0+c = 2, \\
  a(4)^2 + b*4 + 2 = 2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$ Do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @F.Zer Correct! I made a mistake, sorry. So now you have $b=-4a$. Now you could take the quadratic equation and do something what is called "complete the squre". You know how to do that?

Comment: I know how to complete the square. What do you suggest?